# Is there a way to get all the labels for a node in SDN 4.0

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I want to get all the labels belongs to a node, if there a way to do this in one query in SDN 4.0?

For example, my current repo is like

```
Book findById(Long bookId);

@Query("MATCH (n:Book) where id(n)={0} set n:AnotherLabel return n")
Book updateBookLabel(Long bookId);
```

is there anyway I can simply

```
book.getLabels();
```

to retrieve all the labels for this book node.

the class for book is

```
@NodeEntity
public class Book extends Something {
}
```

Yes, by default, my Book node should has two label `Book` and `Something`.Since I have a update method in the repo to add another label. Anyway I can retrieve the book with all 3 labels?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is via a custom query -

```
@Query("MATCH (n:Book) where id(n)={0} return labels(n) as labels")
List<String> getBookLabels(Long bookId);
```

*(untested)*

***Update based on comment***

To return labels and the node properties in a single query, use a @QueryResult-

**SDN 4.0** (cannot map nodes and relationships from a custom query to domain entities in a query result):

```
@QueryResult
public class BookResult {
    Long id;
    Map<String,Object> node;
    List<String> labels;
 }

@Query("MATCH (n:Book) where id(n)={0} return labels(n) as labels, ID(n) as id, {properties: n} as node")
BookResult getBookLabels(Long bookId);
```

**SDN 4.1**

```
 @QueryResult
 public class BookResult {
      Book node;
      List<String> labels;
 }

 @Query("MATCH (n:Book) where id(n)={0} return labels(n) as labels, n as node")
 BookResult getBookLabels(Long bookId);
```

Comment: so, if I have a book id and I want to retrieve the info of book including its labels, then I need 2 queries. First one for the book info, 2nd one for the labels?

Comment: Updated my answer, you can use a single query

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible here is a working example

**Entity**

```
public class Book {
  @Labels
  Set<String> labels= new HashSet<>();
  private Long id;
}
```

**Repo**

```
public interface BookRepository extends GraphRepository<Book> 
{
}
```

That var labels will contain all labels of a node, because it is annotated with `@Label`, so you can do `book.getlabel()` or even `setLabel()` when you want, if you want.

I used *spring boot 1.4.0* and *neo4j community 3.0.4* for this example.