# Spring-data-neo4j get nodes and labels

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am currently usring **Spring** and **neo4j**. One mission is to display the graph using **linkurious**. However, how can I tell Spring through **spring-data-neo4j** the labels of the nodes? I need the labels to color the graph in linkurious. If using `findAll()` defined in the graph repository, only node properties will be returned?

Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**

I tried to use `@QueryResult`, but there's something wrong with the respond. To be more specific:

I define

```
@QueryResult
public class NodeWithLabel {
    GLNode glNode;
    ArrayList<String> labels;
}
```

then in the repository, I have

```
@Query("MATCH (n:GLNode) RETURN n AS glNode, labels(n) as labels")
Collection<NodeWithLabel> getAllNodesWithLabel();
```

Finally, I will get a result with `ArrayList<E>`, so the spring mvc will respond empty like `[{},{},{},{}]`. Normally, such as the embedded `findAll()` function, a `LinkedHashSet<E>` should be returned, in this case, the spring mvc can send back a json respond.

Comment: Do you want the labels of all nodes or some nodes? I just answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978001/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-the-labels-for-a-node-in-sdn-4-0 if it helps. And which version of SDN?

Comment: @Luanne Actually, I need both the nodes and lables. I have updated my question to be more specific. It's SDN 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDN 4.0 does not map nodes/relations to domain entities in a @QueryResult. The code you've posted will work with SDN 4.1

If you want to achieve the same in SDN 4.0, you can do this:

```
@QueryResult
public class NodeWithLabel {
    Long id;
    Map<String,Object> node;
    ArrayList<String> labels;
}


@Query("MATCH (n:GLNode) RETURN ID(n) as id, labels(n) as labels, {properties : n} as node")
Collection<NodeWithLabel> getAllNodesWithLabel();
```

Note: *Strongly recommend that you plan to upgrade to SDN 4.1*

Comment: Oh, yeah. BTW, I have to add the getters function for `NodeWithLabel` class in order to make spring mvc respond to HTTP request correctly.,